# Encounter Error for generating Radio button from Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i am trying to generate radio button from model but getting object reference error. i just can not understand where i am making mistake in MVC because i am just learning it. here is my full code. please have a look and tell me where is the mistake. thanks

### model class

```
 public class StudentModel
    {

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name Required")] // textboxes will show
        [Display(Name = "First Name :")]
        [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "First Name cannot be longer than 5 characters.")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name Required")] // textboxes will show
        [Display(Name = "Last Name :")]
        [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Last Name cannot be longer than 5 characters.")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Sex Required")]
        [Display(Name = "Sex :")]
        public int SexID { get; set; }

        public List<Sex> Sex { get; set; }

    }

    public class Sex
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
```

### controller class

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
            var student = new StudentModel
            {
                FirstName = "Rion",
                LastName = "Gomes",

                //I think the best way to populate this list is to call a service here.
                Sex = new List<Sex>
                {
                    new Sex{ID="1" , Type = "Male"}, 
                    new Sex{ID="2" , Type = "Female"}
                }
            };

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(StudentModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //TODO: Save your model and redirect 
            }

            //Call the same service to initialize your model again (cause we didn't post the list of sexs)
            return View(model);
        }
}
```

### view code

```
@model MvcRadioButton.Models.StudentModel

@Html.BeginForm()
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>
    @{ 
        foreach (var sex in Model.Sex)
        {
            <div>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Sex, new { id = "sex" + sex.ID })
                @Html.Label("sex" + sex.ID, sex.Type)
            </div>
        }
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

this line throwing error

```
foreach (var sex in Model.Sex) saying model null or object reference error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never return a model to your view when the page is initially served.  As a result, when you try to iterate over the `Sex` object you get the null reference error.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ... code ...
    return View(); //The problem is here!
}
```

You should be returning a model to your view:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ... code ...
    return View(student);
}
```

Comment: i notice one problem that radio button having two id attribute like <input id="Sex" type="radio" value="{ id = sex1 }" name="Sex"> why value="{ id = sex1 }" is showing rather it shoudl show id="sex1". plzz guide me what i need to change in my code. thanks

Comment: am i binding radio button properly or not.

Comment: another problem i notice that when i click on submit button then i saw public ActionResult Index(StudentModel model) model Sex property count is 0 why. i select radio button when submit but no value comes at action method end.....any reason.

Comment: You should start reading documentation and or looking at the parameters that methods take.  When you call `RadioButtonFor` the second argument is the `value` of the radio button.  The rendered output is correct based on that.  If you want to add HTML attributes to the element, that should be the third parameter.